API buton Validate width Home Assistant
With Home assistant, I try to take control of my Smartphone from my computer. I have already managed to do some very nice things. Here is an example in pictures.

However, I am currently encountering a problem.
Here is an example of my commands that allow me to validate things on my phone.
type: custom:stack-in-card
title: Appels & SMS
cards:
  - type: horizontal-stack
    cards:
      - type: entities
        entities:
          - entity: input_text.callnumber
            icon: mdi:dialpad
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:trash-can
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: input_text.set_value
          data:
            value: ''
          target:
            entity_id: input_text.callnumber
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
  - type: horizontal-stack
    cards:
      - type: entities
        entities:
          - entity: input_text.smstext
            icon: mdi:text
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:trash-can
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: input_text.set_value
          data:
            value: ''
          target:
            entity_id: input_text.smstext
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
  - type: horizontal-stack
    cards:
      - type: markdown
        content: >-
          Message de : {{state_attr('sensor.redmi_last_notification' ,
          'android.title')}}
          {{states('sensor.redmi_last_notification')}}           
  - type: horizontal-stack
    cards:
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '1'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '1'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '2'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '2'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '3'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '3'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '4'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '4'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '5'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '5'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '6'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '6'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:phone-cancel
        color: red
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615554191
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:microphone
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_launch_app
            data:
              package_name: com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:comment
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_launch_app
            data:
              package_name: com.google.android.apps.messaging
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:google-assistant
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_activity
            data:
              intent_action: android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      
  - type: horizontal-stack
    cards:
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '7'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '7'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '8'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '8'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '9'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '9'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '*'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '*'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '0'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '0'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        name: '#'
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615679662
          service_data:
            number: '#'
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:phone
        color: green
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615643818
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:message
        color: blue
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: script.1708615761003
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:eye
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_screen_on
            data:
              priority: high
        styles:
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'
      - type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:google-assistant
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_activity
            data:
              intent_action: android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e' 

 

The part that interests us is this one.
- type: custom:button-card
        icon: mdi:google-assistant
        color: white
        tap_action:
          action: call-service
          service: notify.mobile_app_redmi
          data:
            message: command_activity
            data:
              intent_action: android.intent.action.xxxxxxxx
          card:
            - width: 40px
            - height: 40px
            - color: '#44739e'

When I connect to certain applications with Home assistant on my phone, I must validate a right of consent.

What intent_action should I put to validate COMMENCER?
